# Regex Between 2 /

Tags: php, regex

i have a string that can be either `/mens/plain/`  or `/mens/plain`

I wish to get just the `plain` from the string, how would i do this with regex. Bare in mind mens and plain will be different each time. My regex system will be php

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for regex - use the [basename](http://php.net/manual/function.basename.php) function instead. To illustrate:

```
echo basename('/mens/plain/');
echo basename('/mens/plain');
```

Comment: As simple as it gets :) Additionally, `explode()` can be a nice tool to analyse strings of arbitrary length that follow this format.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario - If it wasn't for the `/` as the separator, I'd use `explode` ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "/mens/plain/";
if (preg_match('|([^/]+)/?$|', $str, $matches))
    echo $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode()`

```
$segments = array_filter(explode('/', $path));
```

`array_filter()` will remove every empty string. After that, you can access the values directly through their "position" as index of the array

```
echo $segments[1]; // 'plain'
```